# If $φ: A → B$ and $ψ: B → C$ are homomorphisms, then $ψ \circ φ: A → C$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, function-and-relation-composition, ring-homomorphism

Being $A, B$ and $C$ rings. To prove the above statement, I need to show that $ ψ \circ φ: A → C $ satisfies the following conditions:

i) $ψ \circ φ (a + b) = ψ \circ φ (a) + ψ \circ φ (b)$ $\forall$ $a,b \in A$

ii) $ψ \circ φ (ab) = ψ \circ φ (a) ψ \circ φ (b)$ $\forall$ $a,b \in A$

This is my thinking about this demonstration, but I do not know how to do it.

Let $a, b \in A$. Assume $ψ$ and $φ$ homomorphisms.

$ψ \circ φ(a + b)=ψ(φ(a+b))=ψ(φ(a)+φ(b))=ψ(φ(a))+ψ(φ(b))=ψ \circ φ(a)+ψ \circ φ(b)$

and

$ψ \circ φ(ab)=ψ(φ(ab))=ψ(φ(a)φ(b))=ψ(φ(a))ψ(φ(b))=ψ \circ φ(a)ψ \circ φ(b)$

Could you tell me if this approach is correct?

Comment: Hint: $\psi \circ \phi(a+b) = \psi(\phi(a+b))$...

Comment: A composition is applying one map and then the other, so how about you apply the first map, use the definition of homomorphism to simplify, and then apply the second.

Comment: One minute, I'll write.

Comment: If your rings are assumed to have a unit, remember also that a homorphism $f$ has the requirement that $f(1)=1$

Comment: $ψ∘ϕ(a+b)$

$=ψ(ϕ(a+b))$

$=ψ(ϕ(a)+ϕ(b))$ ; because $ϕ$ is homomorphism

$=ψ(ϕ(a))+ψ(ϕ(b))$ ; because $ψ$ is homomorphism

$=ψ∘ϕ(a)+ψ∘ϕ(b)$